# How do I distribute flexbox items on multiple lines evenly?

Tags: css, distribution, flexbox

I am working on a menu bar that has all of its buttons distributed evenly in the center of the nav element (the container). I need this layout to look good on most devices, regardless of its size. The problem is, at one of the tablet sizes I am testing, only one of the buttons goes to the next line, leaving an undesirable look. Is there any way using css to have all items distributed on all lines being used evenly?

Here is the nav's style block:

```
nav {
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Please post the CSS rules concerning children of `nav` and its HTML code

Comment: Here is the code if that helps (both style and framework): http://www.sourcepod.com/ksavyd48-17420

Comment: I don't see a reason to be using flexbox here at all.  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/fLAph